# Passing index as argument in Javascript with setElementAttribute()

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onclick, arguments, parameter-passing

I want to pass an index as an argument to the splatImg() function, which converts a bug image to a splat image upon receving a specific id. However, the console returns `<img id ="0" onclick = "splatImg(i)" src = "file:///C:/Users/luhan/Downloads/images/bugImage.jpg"/>` rather than `<img id ="0" onclick = "splatImg(0/1/2/3/4)" src = "file:///C:/Users/luhan/Downloads/images/bugImage.jpg"/>`

HTML:

```html
<div id ="div1"> </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function createImg()
{   
    img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/bugImage.jpg";
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        img[i]= document.createElement("img");
        img[i].setAttribute("id", [i]);
        img[i].setAttribute("onclick", "splatImg(i)");
        img[i].src = img.src;
        document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(img[i]);
    }
}

function splatImg(id)               
{
    BUGS_CONDITION = [true, true, true, true];
    BUGS = ["bug1", "bug2", "bug3", "bug4"];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {   
        if (BUGS_CONDITION[i])  
        {
            document.getElementById(id).src = "images/bugSplat.jpg";
            removeBug = BUGS.splice(0, 1);
            BUGS_CONDITION[i] = false;
            console.log(BUGS);
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: You've already succeeded why does this post even exist? `function splatImg(id)` see the id inside the parenthesis? That's where the index (I assume id stands for index) gets passed as an argument. Congratulations! Please remove this post as you have already accomplished what you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry, I have not clarified my issue.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I noticed. It looks like your setting the id to an array:

```
img[i].setAttribute("id", [i]);
```

Instead, it should be:

```
img[i].setAttribute("id", i);
```

And when your calling the function, it's just passing the letter "i" rather than the index, so instead of:

```
"splatImg(i)"
```

You should have (note: it's using a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)):

```
`splatImg(${i})`
```

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty to new Javascript. Could you please explain what `splatImg(${i})` do? Thank you very much.

Comment: I've put in a link to explain template strings (template literals). Basically in this case it allows you to do that instead of ```"splatImg(" + i + ")"```, which is a bit uglier.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Added to execute the code here
window.onload = function() { createImg(); };

function createImg()
{   
    // No need to create an image to hold its src
    var src = "images/bugImage.jpg";
    // img should be an array
    var img = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        img[i]= document.createElement("img");
        // Numerical index can be hard to manage
        // So I've changed to alphanumerical
        img[i].setAttribute("id", 'img-' + i);
        img[i].onclick = function() {
            // Send image object instead a variable
            splatImg(this);
        };
        img[i].src = src;
        document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(img[i]);
    }
}

function splatImg(img)               
{
    var BUGS_CONDITION = [true, true, true, true];
    var BUGS = ["bug1", "bug2", "bug3", "bug4"];
    // Get number from img.id
    var id = img.id.split('-')[1];
    BUGS_CONDITION[id] = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (BUGS_CONDITION[i])  
        {
            img.src = "images/bugSplat.jpg";
            // Remove the bug, no new variable needed
            BUGS.splice(id, 1);
            BUGS_CONDITION[i] = false;
            console.log(BUGS);
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}
You had some errors that I've commented directly in code
```

```html
<div id ="div1"> </div>
```